# Django formtools done function not executed

Tags: django, django-formwizard, django-formtools

I am trying to implement the formwizard in django. The steps work as expected, but aftet the final form (second step) is submitted, the done function is not hit. I am not able to find the reason why. Kindly direct. Following is my code,

Forms.py

```
from django import forms

class FormStepOne(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()

class FormStepTwo(forms.Form):
    otp = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FormStepOne, FormStepTwo
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.
class FormWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'done.html'
    form_list = [FormStepOne, FormStepTwo]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        print('done')
        return render(self.request, 'home.html', {'form_data':[form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

    def process_step(self, form):
        # print(self.get_form_step_data(form)['0-email'])
        # print(self.steps.current)
        if self.steps.current == '0':
            print('send mail to ' + self.get_form_step_data(form)['0-email'])
        else:
            print('verify the entered otp')
```

I want to send a mail with otp after 1st step is submitted, and then in the second step I ask for the otp that was sent in first step for verification. And by default, after submitting the last step the page is redirected to step 1. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my query above. It seems the done wasn't executing due to the process_step(). I just commented the process_step() function and the done() function got executed. Guess I will have to dive deeper into it.