# Django formtools Wizard done function not executed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-formwizard, django-formtools

(References:

1. [Django formtools done function not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635382/django-formtools-done-function-not-executed)
2. https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/formtools/wizard/views.html#WizardView
3. https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#wizardview-advanced-methods
   )

I am trying to do the same thing. The steps are working and individual form data able to get, but after the submit button is clicked and final form is submitted, I expect all three form data to be submitted at once and the done function has to process that but it is not happening. I am not able to find the reason why. Because of policy I can't share the code but putting a dummy code here and logic what I am implementing. Kindly please direct. Following is my code,

(This is a Edit Form I am trying to create, in each form init method is also overrided for initial data wrt pk, this all is working not an issue)

done.html

```
{% extends CURRENT_TEMPLATE %}  
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
Hi you are watching done.html
{{ data }}
{% endblock content %}
```

form.html

```
{% extends CURRENT_TEMPLATE %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form.as_table }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
</table>

{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}

{% if wizard.steps.next %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.next }}">{% trans "next step" %}</button>
{% endif %}

{% if not wizard.steps.next %}
<button type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}">{% trans "Submit"  %}</button>
{% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms

class RouteEditForm1(ModelForm):
    field1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        model = MainModel
        fields = ['field2','field3']

class RouteEditForm2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MainModel
        fields = ['field4','field5']

class RouteEditForm3(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MainModel
        fields = ['field6','field7']
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RouteEditForm1, RouteEditForm2, RouteEditForm3
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

# Create your views here.
class RouteEditView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "form.html"
    form_list = [RouteEditForm1, RouteEditForm2, RouteEditForm3]

    #  following functions are in order of their call
    # This is working
    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        print("\n ----------------- inside get_form step ",self.steps.current)
        form = super().get_form(step, data, files)
        # determine the step if not given
        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current
        if step == '1':
            form.user = self.request.user
        return form
    # This is working
    def get_form_kwargs(self, step):
        print("\n ----------------- inside get_form_kwargs ", step)
        kwargs = super(RouteEditView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        # print("self.request ", self.request)
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        # print("get_form_kwargs  kwargs ", kwargs)
        return kwargs
    # This is working
    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        print("\n ----------------- inside get_form_initial step ", step)
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            try:
                pk = self.kwargs['pk']
                if pk is None:
                    print("\n ---------get_form_initial--------  pk is none ")
                else:
                    pk = Getid(self.request, pk)
                    print("\n ---------get_form_initial--------  pk is  ", pk)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception in get_form_initial ", e)
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()
                messages.warning(
                    self.request, "Unable to process your request.")
            return {}
        else:
            return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
    # This is working
    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        print("\n ----------------- inside get_form_instance step ", step)
        # step 0: user form
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            pk = self.kwargs['pk']
            pk = Getid(self.request, pk)

        # The default implementation
        return self.instance_dict.get(step, None)
    
    # This is working
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        print("\n ----------------- get_context_data  step ",self.steps.current)
        try:
            # print("\n inside get_context_data step try", self.steps.current)
            context = super(RouteEditView, self).get_context_data(
                form=form, **kwargs)
            context.update({'another_var': "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"})
            type = "Edit"
            head = "Route Details"
            context.update(
                {'type': type, 'head': head, "request": self.request})
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception in get_context_data ", e)
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()

        return context

    # This is not Working
    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        print("\n -----------------  done step ", self.steps.current)
        try:
            form_dict2 = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
            # print("\n done method ", form_dict2)
            form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
            return render(self.request, 'done.html', {'data':form_data})
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception in done ", e)
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
```

And also after submitting the final form at last step the page is redirected to step 1 again. Why?